# The normalizer of a torus is a closed subgroup of the Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $T \subset G$ a torus, show that $N(T)$ is a closed subgroup of $G$.  Could somebody give a sketch of the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $n_i\in N(T)$ converges to $n$, and let $t\in T$.
Then $$n_itn_i^{-1}\rightarrow ntn^{-1}.$$
Since $n_itn_i^{-1}\in T$ we have $ntn^{-1}\in T$ since $T$ is closed.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  So the key is $T$ is closed, which is true because of its monogenicity, right?

Comment: Yeah, it seem to hold for any closed subgroup. Sorry, I cant remember what monogenicity means at the moment.